# How to find hardware device id from a direct sound device?

Tags: flutter, windows, directsound

I need to enumerate direct sound devices on windows, and serialise the actual device used to output a particular channel. This appears to be done normally by saving the direct sound device GUID. However, I need to connect to the same hardware if it exists on a different computer. I've tried using the GUID, but that is different on different computers with exactly the same audio device plugged in.

I believe since it's the audio hardware which I'm binding to, rather than a role, I should be using a device interface path, as shown in Windows device manager, but there doesn't seem to be a way to go from the direct sound object to the device manager path.

Is it possible to make this mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example found here: [http://www.chrisnet.net/code.htm](https://web.archive.org/web/20190929033826/http://www.chrisnet.net/code.htm) which shows how to use the `CLSID_DirectSoundPrivate` interface, which is non-trivial, almost impossible to find via MSDN if you don't know what to look for, and has a terrible interface involving multiple calls which is not explained anywhere other than in this example.

I took this example, and ended up getting stack violations attempting to call the `Get` method on the property set.

It turns out that direct show defines the same `IKsPropertySet` interface with the same guid but with a different vtable, causing horrible vtable-related problems if you `#include` `dshow.h` or `strmif.h` before `dsound.h`. Needless to say, I'm unimpressed.

The calls needed are as follows:

```
hr = pKsPropertySet->Get(DSPROPSETID_DirectSoundDevice, 
        DSPROPERTY_DIRECTSOUNDDEVICE_DESCRIPTION, 
        NULL, 
        0, 
        &sDirectSoundDeviceDescription, 
        sizeof(sDirectSoundDeviceDescription), 
        &ulBytesReturned
    ); 

if (ulBytesReturned)
{
    // On the first call it notifies us of the required amount of memory in order to receive the strings.
    // Allocate the required memory, the strings will be pointed to the memory space directly after the struct.
    psDirectSoundDeviceDescription = (PDSPROPERTY_DIRECTSOUNDDEVICE_DESCRIPTION_DATA)new BYTE[ulBytesReturned];
    *psDirectSoundDeviceDescription = sDirectSoundDeviceDescription;

    hr = pKsPropertySet->Get(DSPROPSETID_DirectSoundDevice, 
            DSPROPERTY_DIRECTSOUNDDEVICE_DESCRIPTION, 
            NULL, 
            0, 
            psDirectSoundDeviceDescription, 
            ulBytesReturned, 
            &ulBytesReturned
        );
```